# Android studio crashing when i type codes inside an xml file using android studio electric eel

Tags: android-studio, crash

After I installed the latest version (Electric Eel) I can't write codes. Every time I open an XML file in android studio, it seems to crash and it takes a long time for code suggestions to appear. I use windows 10, with the latest updates, I installed ubuntu and it works normally... When I write code in kotlin files this problem does not appear, everything works normally, but when I change to any XML file it happens.

Has anyone had the same problem with this version (Electric Eel) or any other previous version?

Does anyone know how I can download the dolphin version? I searched and couldn't find any official link.

I increased the dedicated RAM inside the AS and even then I didn't have different results.

Comment: You might wanna [submit a bug report](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs) for this, as this will send IDE logs and more information needed to figure out why this is happening. Some suggestions that might work: go to File>Invalidate Caches..., restart and try again. Disable plugins that might be related and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up using an earlier version of AS. Now in the new version the bug has been fixed.